# Review page is painfully slow

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, performance

I have noticed that the review page is slow and takes a huge amount of time to load (if at all). I noticed this at work as well as at home. The rest of the site seems fast, its really just this one page that seems to be consistently slow.

Comment: Most likely a problem with your connection or computer.

Comment: So my computer has a problem with just one stack overflow page ?

Comment: Or browser perhaps? That could explain the behaviour at home as well as at work...

Comment: Ie8 at work, ie9 at home, two separate computers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yup, certain Review pages currently load comically slow. For example, we kindly ask that you *never* pay a visit to the "all" sub-tab of the "low quality" tab on Stack Overflow's review page. (You'll occasionally be greeted by a literally 2-minute page load).

We're working on overhauling the Review page entirely, which will take care of the current performance issues.

Comment: "we kindly ask that you never pay a visit to..." ... you realize what's going to happen, right? ;)

Comment: @Bart That's OK, they need some people to let the new moderators test out the ban button on.

Comment: @TimStone /me walks away whistling innocently

Comment: Morbid curiosity engage