# Review Queue Very Slow To Load

Tags: bug, review

I figured this was a problem with my ISP, but it happened on two separate internet connections now. The review queue is painfully slow to load the first question, and go from question to question. Anywhere between 6-12 seconds per load and only happens in the review queues.

I found [Review page is painfully slow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136034/review-page-is-painfully-slow) from last year which says it was problem previously. But is there a new issue with these pages?

[image: Chrome Developer Tools network tab]

[image: Reproduced]

Comment: One try is not a data set. Can you try it many times and give us an average?

Comment: Or your build of Chrome is buggy and the V8 engine has a memory leak?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I can try to give you the developer tools run down if there's enough in the queues. Like I said, I've seen 6-12 seconds, probably averaging 7 seconds. I'm using the standard release of Chrome 26 on Windows 7 64-bit and has been going on for a couple of days. It could be a Chrome issue, but I'm not seeing issues anywhere else on the Internet.

Comment: Yah, they load just fine here. Chrome 27.

Comment: Added another screenshot of the developer tools with the issue reproduced twice.

Comment: I +1 this, but _only_ for the First Posts and Late Answers queues. Every other queue is fine.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I don't have enough rep for other other queues, so I didn't know exactly what it affected.

Comment: No issues here in any of the SO review/10K/20K tool screens in Chrome 26.0.1410.64 (just clicked through all of them).

Comment: I'm also experiencing very slow loading times - same as @KnightswhosayNi: only on First Posts and Late Answers.

Comment: I'd usually put this down to the n^12 tabs I have open, but on a separate box, I'm getting the same in some cases.

Comment: Yeh, I've been getting a lot of slow review loading times.